# HTML entities in an ArcGIS web appbuilder chart widget

Tags: html, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I’m working on an ArcGIS `web appbuilder` page that displays a donut/pie chart.

Some of the categories contain the character `<` which is rendered as `&lt;` in the labels but as `<` in the tooltips:

[image]

Is this an ArcGIS bug, or a parameter I missed?